# LiveData using ViewModel for aidl Remote service callbacks

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I have an activity bound to an aidl service.
Activity passes data to the aidl remote service.
Remote service passes data back to activity using callbacks.

I want to preserve data that is passed from service to activity using LiveData and ViewModel.

[image]

Is there a good design for this problem?

Comment: see `AndroidViewModel` - it has a `Context` you can use for service binding

Comment: And see [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/FINAL/Sensor/LiveService) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Can you check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552240/10271334, I can provide some guideline about how you can achieve such thing.