# MVVM communication between Service and ViewModel

Tags: android, android-service, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I have a `Service` that loads data from via http request every second.

I am wondering how to implement the service in my current MVVM structure.

A solution I could think of is to:

1. `View` calls method from `ViewModel`
2. `ViewModel` calls method from `Repository`
3. Start the `Service` in the `Repository` and pass in some `LiveData`, as Repositories should be responsible for data loading.
4. Update this `LiveData` in the `Service` via `postValue()`.
5. Observe this `LiveData` in UI and notify the `ViewModel` of the changes
6. In `ViewModel` get the changed `LiveData` and update the other LiveData for the View accordingly
7. Stop the `Service` based on the outcome of step 6

However, I am wondering if there is no better solution with a more direct communication from `Service` to `ViewModel` or even from `Service` to `Repository` to `ViewModel`

Comment: Personally, I haven't got chance to implement such scenario yet but if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552240/10271334 can help you understanding correct implementation. There might be technical difficulty solving this but I'll be here to help you out.

Comment: I still can't tell an optimal process. However by now I found out, that using step 5 and 6, can be replaced by using ```Transformations.map()``` in the viewmodel.